# how to set repeating-background image to UITableCell

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview, background, repeat

When I set repeating background image to a UITableView by using the following code is ok:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

but when I use it to set repeating-background image to a UITableViewCell by following code, nothing happen, I don't know why, I also cannot set background color to this cell too.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

Is there anyone know the way to so this? please help me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"]];
```

which would go inside this code block:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[RecipeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"]];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-on.png"]];
    }    
// Configure cell

return cell;
}
```

You can also see how to set the selected image in inside there too: selectedBackgroundView.

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-pressed.png"]];
```

I'm unsure about repeating, but I'm pretty sure backgroundView can have contentMode set on it.

Comment: Dear Kolin, thanks for your answer! about this solution, I knew it already. I ask for repeating-background image in order to not have to change background image in landscape mode.

Comment: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"] drawAsPatternInRect:yourRect];

Comment: See if this works if you make a Rect inside your contentview.

Comment: -1 This answer does not resolve the question, which is specifically about **repeating** images.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, it is more easier than I think. I just need to set background image by following code:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

and the whole cell background view is automatically filled with this background image. :)

Comment: but the image is stretched